# ActiveMQ-Stomp consumer does not get messages

Tags: javascript, websocket, activemq-classic, publish-subscribe

I wrote following js code in order to make a `ActiveMQ` subscriber that subscribes to a specific topic, but it does not receive any message after connection.

The topic name to be subscribed is **COO.255227045008372**

```
var client = Stomp.client("ws://localhost:61614?consumer.prefetchSize=1","v11.stomp");
client.debug = null;
var selectedVehicleImei = 255227045008372;
client.connect("", "", function (topic) {
    client.subscribe("COO." + selectedVehicleImei, function (message) {
        var infodata = JSON.parse(message.body);
        console.log(infodata);
    })
})
```

**In Admin console**

`Queue` section displays a queue named `COO.255227045008372`.

`Topic` section displays following topic names,

- `ActiveMQ.Advisory.Consumer.Queue.COO.255227045008372`
- `ActiveMQ.Advisory.Producer.Topic.COO.255227045008372`
- `COO.255227045008372`

I only used Topics but here i can see Queues also. Is this the problem ?, i'm new to `ActiveMQ` things so, can anyone help me to make this work, please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the fix, i put `/topic/` prefix to the topic here, as the docs suggest to prevent fallback to `queue` now it works.